# CollectionView Compositional Layout with Multiple Data Types

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, diffabledatasource

I was playing around with Compositional Layouts with Diffable DataSource and so far loving it. But all of my endeavors have included a single type of Data Item.

What I'm trying to achieve is have two different types of List, say `Car` and `Airplane`

So far what I've done is created the layouts, created an `Enum`

```
enum DataItem: Hashable{
    case cars(Car)
    case airplane(Airplane)
}
```

And `dataSource` initialization:

```
func configureDataSource(){
    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource
    <Section, DataItem>(collectionView: collectionView) {
        (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, dataItem: DataItem) -> UICollectionViewCell in
        
        switch dataItem {
        case .cars(let car):
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CarCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CarCell else {fatalError("Couldn't Create New Cell")}
            ....
            return cell
        case .airplanes(let airplane):
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AirplaneCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AirplaneCell else {
                fatalError("Couldn't Create New Cell")
            }
            ....
            return cell
        }
    }
    dataSource.apply(snapshotForCurrentState(), animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

Now the part that I'm stuck is creating the snapshot.

Ideally what I'd like to do is

```
func snapshotForCurrentState() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, DataItem>{
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, DataItem>()
    snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)
    snapshot.appendItems([cars], toSection: Section.cars)
    snapshot.appendItems([airplanes], toSection: Section.airplanes)
    return snapshot
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In order for custom `ItemIdentifier` types (e.g. `DataItem`) to synthesize `Hashable` conformance, their enum case associated types (e.g. `Car` and `Airplane`) have to manually add `Hashable` conformance.

Answer (score 9):

You're on the right path. The part you're missing is that you need to create your snapshot with the aggregated type you created, `DataItem`.

```
func snapshotForCurrentState() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, DataItem>{
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, DataItem>()
    snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)

    let carItems = cars.map { DataItem.car($0) }
    snapshot.appendItems(carItems, toSection: Section.cars)

    let airplaneItems = airplanes.map { DataItem.airplane($0) }
    snapshot.appendItems(airplaneItems, toSection: Section.airplanes)
    return snapshot
}
```